# bind text + ".jpg" as ImageUrl in <asp:Image> control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I do have an Image control in a c# web.

I want to bind a value as "ImageUrl", but I do want to concat the string .jpg to this value first.

```
 <p><asp:Image id=Imagen1 runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Id_product") %>'/>  </p>
```

I tryed +".jpg", also + '.jpg', but didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: I thought maybe adding a "hidden" asp:image, just binding the Id_Product, and then taking this text as "base" to concat with ".jpg", and then fill the real asp:image... but no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<asp:Image id="Imagen1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Id_product") + ".jpg" %>' />
```

Updated the code. This has been tested and it works.

Comment: didn't work :( but thanks anyway <3.    
 it sent the whole value to the image-url. 
checking f11 on chrome seems like:
<img src=%20#%20Bind("Id_product")%20>.jpg">

Comment: I have updated the code. Use Eval instead of Bind. I have tested this to be working.